# Unable to update to version 1.0.0 from 1.00-rc1-final

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dnx

I have [this](https://github.com/Adipa-G/AngularAndWebAPI/tree/master/mvc6) project created using `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc version 6.0.0-rc1-final`, and it works. But when use the VS2015 package manager to update (some of the packages) it to the latest version 1.0.0.

The error message is,

[image]

So the question is, if the support for .net framework removed from the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 1.0.0?

Is there any particular reasons?

Will the support be added in a future version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your RC1 project to RTM, many things have changed since.

Shawn Wildermuth has two great blogs about updating.

**RC1 -> RC2:** https://wildermuth.com/2016/05/17/Converting-an-ASP-NET-Core-RC1-Project-to-RC2
**RC2 -> 1.0.0 RTM:** https://wildermuth.com/2016/06/27/Converting-ASP-NET-Core-1-0-RC2-to-RTM-Bits

And when your finished don't forget to add `"version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"` to your global.json file. This tells Visual Studio which version of ASP.NET Core you are using.

You'll also need Visual Studio update 3 in order to use ASP.NET Core 1.0.0.